# In Debian, are there texlive-* packages that reflect the contents of the TexLive collections?

Tags: texlive, debian

I'm using a headless Debian installation and I'm trying to install a subset of TeX Live that 1) doesn't have any of the graphical tools and 2) has only the collections I need.

I'm able to do this directly with the TeX Live installer but I'd like to use `apt-get` instead if possible. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like the texlive packages correspond to the collections in any meaningful manner? For example, `latexmk` seems to be in its own package, as is `lmodern`. I just have to install the "Chinese" collection from TeX Live to get Chinese working but there doesn't seem to be a corresponding Debian package at all (I need to `latex-cjk-all` instead of just `latex-cjk-chinese` or `texlive-lang-chinese`).

Can someone explain the Debian TeX Live packaging to me and how it is related to the TeX Live collections?

Comment: Welcome! What graphical tools? I think this question is really off-topic as it has nothing to do with TeX. It is a question about Debian packaging and would be best asked on a Debian site. That said, you may get lucky and somebody knows and answers, but it isn't really anything to do with TeX itself, or TeX Live. Each distro's packagers make decisions about how to divide up the distribution. The obvious solution is to install upstream's TeX Live, since that is recommended anyway. But if you don't want to, you can only accommodate yourself to your distro's packaging or change distro.

Comment: Assuming you want a subset of the packages included in `texlive-full`, you can look through that package's dependencies and pare it down to the packages you want. For example, if [`latex-cjk-all`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/latex-cjk-all) is too broad, I assume you can install just the Chinese-oriented packages it depends on, like `latex-cjk-chinese`, `latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bkai00mp`, etc. Probably most Debian users here just install from upstream TeX Live, though.

Comment: Note that `collection-langchinese` depends on `collection-langcjk` so you can't have the former without the latter without picking through individual packages and figuring out the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the Debian package names to collections in TeX Live with minimal changes to the names. What is a difference that some packages are sliced out (as you mentioned), mostly due to historic reasons. But in this case you you should get the very same setup as long as recommended packages are installed (the default for apt).

So in up to a certain level you should get the same when installing scheme-minimal and the install a collection using `tlmgr` or when installing the respective `texlive-*` package.